# Matrix equation with powers $A\cdot X^T=B$

Tags: matrices, exponentiation

*Given the matrix equation $A\cdot X^T=B$, isolate the matrix $X$ and identify the order of the matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $X$ has order $3\times5$*

---

I came across these matrix equations, and I cannot comprehend what is the power of $T$ doing there, and how to isolate it. The problem doesn´t even say what is the nature of $T$.

The first obvious step is:

$$X^T=A^{-1}B$$

But how can I deal whit the other power?

Comment: $X^T$ is for the **transpose** of the matrix $X$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose

Comment: $T$ is not a power, it stands for transpose.

Comment: Can you please change $T$ to something else, for example $n$, it is similar to transpose and confusing.

Comment: Jesus, how could i forget about the transpose